# Reading SMS and MMS Database in Android

Tags: android, database, sms, mms

Google is providing a very nice documentation of the contacts provider in Android API. (You can see it [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html). It has a full details of all tables and columns names used in these databases. 
I tried to look for the same for sms and mms databases (which are located in mmssms.db) but I could not see any documentation for that. So my questions are:

- First, is it true that there is no such documentation ?
- If yes, why google tried to keep this away from us ?
- And, in your opinion, how can I get more details about the tables used and a description of each column in that table (i.e. what each column is used for).

By the way, I need this information to write a java program that will read sms/mms data. You can assume that I already got mmssms.db file.

Thanks, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no official documentation about sms and mms database in android
2. ............
3. You can get a lot of information about what each column is used for from the `Telephony.java`. You can get the file here. [Telephony.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java)